# How to install ubuntu on windows 7 using ISO with no disk?

Tags: windows-7, system-installation, disk

I need to know how I can install ubuntu on Windows using the ISO file without burning onto a disk. Is this possible?

Comment: With no disk do you mean without a DVD or a USB media, right?

Comment: yes, I do mean that

Comment: Everyone is telling me to use USB. There has to be a minor difference here.

Comment: @Danatela look at the last comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a USB drive.

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu

If you are using Windows you should use Unetbootin:

http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/

or you can download it for Ubuntu from the Software Center.

It is easy to use. Select "Disk image" then click on the "..." button to select your Ubuntu ISO. Before you click on "OK" be sure to select the right USB drive.

[image]

Comment: Acceptable, But doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a DVD or USB drive then you can add a boot entry using [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/), but this is not recommended if you can use a USB drive.

Comment: EasyBCD - Attempt failed.